# How to set GCP IAM role to access AI Platform notebook only?

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-iam, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm trying to give a team member an IAM role to access only AI Notebook.
I set the role as below
 - Notebooks Runner
 - Notebooks Viewer

However, when the member tries to access Jupyter notebook, 403 Error appears.

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo7X3.png)

The GCP documents says that I should give Editor privileges. But I don't want to give too many privileges.

(https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_403_forbidden_error)

How to set GCP IAM role to access only Jupyter notebook?

Comment: How did you created the Notebook? You can use "proxy-user-mail" option. https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-jupyter-on-a-google-cloud-vm-5ba1b473f4c2

Comment: Thanks, gogasca! I solved problem by changing proxy-mode value from service_account to project_editor